# How much additional processing time is needed for a combination DMZ configuration?

Tags: firewall

Please consider the DMZ configuration shown below.

[image]

(Image source: Testing Web Security: Assessing the Security of Web Sites and Applications by Steven Splaine)

And then let us consider the following (combination) DMZ configuration.

[image]

(Image source: Testing Web Security: Assessing the Security of Web Sites and Applications by Steven Splaine)

If we go for a very straightforward comparison, we see that in the first case, for an external request to be served, the communication packets have to traverse two firewalls (1 incoming, 1 outgoing). In the second scenario, this figure becomes four firewalls (2 plus 2).

Now, if the processing time per firewall is *t*, can we go for the linear computation that in the first case the processing time per external request will be *2t* and in the second case *4t*?

Or are there any other factors we need to take into consideration?

Comment: Presumably the external request is served by servers in the DMZ, so it would be the same.

Comment: @RonTrunk Absolutely, otherwise a DMZ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @RonTrunk No, I wanted to mean that there will be web servers in DMZ which will need to visit application and/or DB servers in the core/internal zone to formulate the complete response.